# JUnit and Hibernate 2nd lvl cache

Tags: hibernate, junit5, jcache

I have couple of entities and DAO for work with database, all working fine without second level cache. But when enabling cache - obj in cache not updating with CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE or CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL. Only with CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONE all working fine. Any ideas how to fix it?

Last assert return 42, but in DB already 140

Entity

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

import java.util.Objects;

@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
@Entity
@Table(name = "purchased_products", schema = "purchase", catalog = "onlineshop_purchase")
public class PurchasedProducts {

    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    /**
     * Couple of "PurchasedProducts" relating to 1 "Purchase"
     */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "purchase_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Purchase purchase;

    /**
     * Couple of "PurchasedProducts" relating to 1 "Product"
     */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Product product;

    /**
     * Actual price taking from "Product" during creation "PurchasedProducts"
     */
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "product_price", nullable = false, precision = 0)
    private Double productPrice;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "product_qty", nullable = false, precision = 0)
    private Double productQty;

    /**
     * Counting by trigger in DB
     */
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "total_amount", nullable = true, precision = 0)
    private Double totalAmount;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        PurchasedProducts that = (PurchasedProducts) o;
        return id.equals(that.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

Here is problematic test:

```
    /**
     * Setup data for main tests
     */

    // 1. Creating new Customer
    static CustomerDAOImpl customerDAO = new CustomerDAOImpl();
    static Customer customer = new Customer();
    static Long customerId;
    static CustomerRoleDAOImpl customerRoleDAO = new CustomerRoleDAOImpl();

    // 2. Creating new Products
    static ProductDAOImpl productDAO = new ProductDAOImpl();
    static Product product1 = new Product();
    static Product product2 = new Product();
    static Double product1Qty = 3D;
    static Double product2Qty = 2D;
    static Long product1Id;
    static Long product2Id;

    // 3. Creating new Purchase
    static PurchaseDAOImpl purchaseDAO = new PurchaseDAOImpl();
    static Purchase purchase = new Purchase();
    static Long purchaseId;

    // 4. Creating list with purchased products
    static PurchasedProductsDAOImpl purchasedProductsDAO = new PurchasedProductsDAOImpl();
    static PurchasedProducts purchasedProduct1 = new PurchasedProducts();
    static Long purchasedProduct1Id;
    static PurchasedProducts purchasedProduct2 = new PurchasedProducts();
    static Long purchasedProduct2Id;
    static List<PurchasedProducts> purchasedProducts;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setupAndCheckTestData() {

        // Creating Customer
        customer.setCustomerName("customerNameTest");
        customer.setCustomerSurname("customerSurnameTest");
        customer.setCustomerEmail("customerEmailTest");
        customer.setCustomerPassword("customerPasswordTest");
        customerDAO.add(customer);
        customerId = customer.getId();
        assertTrue(customerDAO.get(customerId).equals(customer));

        // Creating 2 products
        product1.setItem("TestProduct1");
        product1.setPrice(14D);
        product2.setItem("TestProduct2");
        product2.setPrice(19D);
        productDAO.add(product1);
        productDAO.add(product2);
        product1Id = product1.getId();
        product2Id = product2.getId();
        assertEquals(productDAO.get(product1Id), product1);
        assertEquals(productDAO.get(product2Id), product2);

        // Creating new purchase ang getting purchase ID for assigning purchased products
        purchase.setCustomerId(customerId);
        purchaseDAO.add(purchase);
        purchaseId = purchase.getId();


        // Creating 2 purchased products from products
        purchasedProduct1.setPurchase(purchase);
        purchasedProduct1.setProduct(product1);
        purchasedProduct1.setProductQty(product1Qty);
        purchasedProduct1.setProductPrice(product1.getPrice());
        purchasedProductsDAO.add(purchasedProduct1);
        purchasedProduct1Id = purchasedProduct1.getId();

        purchasedProduct2.setPurchase(purchase);
        purchasedProduct2.setProduct(product2);
        purchasedProduct2.setProductQty(product2Qty);
        purchasedProduct2.setProductPrice(product2.getPrice());
        purchasedProductsDAO.add(purchasedProduct2);
        purchasedProduct2Id = purchasedProduct2.getId();
    }

    /**
     * Main functionality tests for PurchasedProducts
     */
    @Test
    void purchasedProducts_Update(){
        // Expected 42 because Product1 price = 14 * product1Qty = 3
        assertEquals(42D, purchasedProductsDAO.get(purchasedProduct1Id).getTotalAmount());

        purchasedProduct1 = purchasedProductsDAO.get(purchasedProduct1Id);
        purchasedProduct1.setProductQty(10D);
        purchasedProductsDAO.update(purchasedProduct1);

        // Expected 140 because Product1 price = 14 * product1Qty = 10
        assertEquals(140D, purchasedProductsDAO.get(purchasedProduct1Id).getTotalAmount().doubleValue());
    }
```

Trigger in PostgreSQL which updating purchase_price

```
DECLARE

    purchaseId INTEGER = new.purchase_id;

BEGIN

    UPDATE purchase.purchase_data SET purchase_price = (SELECT SUM(total_amount) FROM purchase.purchased_products WHERE purchase_id = purchaseId) WHERE id = purchaseId;
    RETURN NEW;

END
```